# Word add-in manifest file - Taskpane URL not accepting MVC

Tags: office365, add-in, office-js, office-addins

Just want to ask for help, it seems like the manifest file does not accept the MVC index.cshtml page that we added in.

The code of the portion of the manifest file can be see below:

```
<bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://appname.azurewebsites.net/Home/Index" />
```

When the add-in is deployed, it shows an error code 13004. The line of code above is the culprit and it seems that it does not recognize the link even if it works on all browsers.

thanks!

Comment: 13004 is an error you should only see when you call getAccessTokenAsync. Is that what you are doing? If not, give exact steps that lead to the error and explain where you see the error.

Comment: That is the error thrown when I call the getAccessTokenAsync.. I'm not really sure why it throws it though.

Answer (score 0):

If url is the problem as you mentioned, you can replace the url provided below to troubleshoot.

Please try the code below:

```
<bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane2.html" />
```

For more information, please review the following link:
[Office Add-ins XML manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1)